# How to sum two variable in REST API

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I want to sum two variable in REST API,and order by it.
This is my REST API:

```
"aggs": {
"genres": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "L7_PROTO_NAME.keyword",
    "order": {
      "sum_bytes": "desc"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "in_bytes": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "IN_BYTES"
      }
    },
    "out_bytes": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "OUT_BYTES"
      }
    }
   }
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another sub-aggregation that sums the two fields and then order the `terms` aggregation by that sub-aggregation:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_index": "logstash-2018.01.02"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "IPV4_DST_ADDR": "192.168.0.159"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "IPV4_SRC_ADDR": "192.168.0.159"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "L7_PROTO_NAME.keyword",
        "order": {
          "sum_bytes": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "in_bytes": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "IN_BYTES"
          }
        },
        "out_bytes": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "OUT_BYTES"
          }
        },
        "sum_bytes": {
          "sum": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc.IN_BYTES.value + doc.OUT_BYTES.value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since scripts are quite computation heavy, you should sum those two fields at indexing time and index the result as a new field that you can use directly in your aggregation, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_index": "logstash-2018.01.02"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "IPV4_DST_ADDR": "192.168.0.159"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "IPV4_SRC_ADDR": "192.168.0.159"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "L7_PROTO_NAME.keyword",
        "order": {
          "sum_bytes": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "in_bytes": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "IN_BYTES"
          }
        },
        "out_bytes": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "OUT_BYTES"
          }
        },
        "sum_bytes": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "SUM_BYTES"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems can run on the "_index": "logstash-2018.01.02".but when I change to "_index": "ntopng-2018.01.02" their data type and field are all the same.it return hits, but didn't agg by genre

Comment: return :{
  "took": 102,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 26,
    "successful": 26,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2148,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "genres": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}

Comment: Which means that the `ntopng-2018.01.02` index doesn't contain documents with the `L7_PROTO_NAME` field

Comment: Can you show a document from `ntopng-2018.01.02` that should match?

Comment: "should": [
        {
            "term":{"IPV4_SRC_ADDR":"120.127.160.91"}
        },
        {
            "term":{"IPV4_DST_ADDR":"120.127.160.91"}
        }
      ],"minimum_should_match": 1,

Comment: A document not a query

Comment: @timestamp          January 3rd 2018, 20:57:42.000
FIRST_SWITCHED 1,514,984,152
IN_BYTES          1,040
IN_PKTS                      10
DST_ADDR      172.217.160.110
IPV4_SRC_ADDR      120.127.163.205
L4_DST_PORT         443
L4_SRC_PORT         60,698
L7_PROTO          126
L7_PROTO_NAME         SSL.Google
LAST_SWITCHED         1,514,984,262
NTOPNG_INSTANCE_NAME DESKTOP-L1VSVD3
OUT_BYTES          0
OUT_PKTS          0
PROTOCOL          6
SRC_IP_COUNTRY         TW
_index          ntopng-2018.01.03
_score         - 
_type          ntopng
type           ntopng

Comment: I have change the date to "ntopng-2018.01.03", and still didn't return  genre but  get hits

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact query you're running + HTTP method + index name, please?

Comment: You shouldn't have removed your original question, as my answer was in that context. it will make it hard for people to understand now.

Comment: sorry, I forgot it .

Comment: The thing is that my answer works for your original question. now your new issue should be another question in my opinion.

Comment: I will modify it later !